# Hadoop operation shutting down the node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running hadoop on a virtual machine inside the code. While doing hdfs operation (copy,..) the virtual machine was shutdown first time and the actual node was shutdown second time.

I am not sure why this is happening and i am not able to see why this happening in any logs either.

Any suggestions/inputs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Being heavy Daemons, all the Hadoop processes are resource intensive, specially RAM. Increase the RAM of your VM and hopefully it would solve the problem. 
(Let me know if it doesn't).

Comment: I have already allocated 7GB, while the system RAM is 8GB. I will look in to this and try to do execute the operation another time

Comment: Once i configured the swap space in the actual node that is hosting the virtual box, this problem did not occur again.